# Can I replace a music toy speaker with a 6.3mm jack?

Tags: speakers, input-impedance, guitar-pedal, music

This toy keytar gas an 8 ohm speaker and adjustable output volume. If I simply replaced the speaker with a 6.3mm jack to use it with guitar pedals and speakers that can handle the line level, would I get any other issues? E.g. impedance problems?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with impedance problems? Also, it's highly unlikely that anyone here knows what kind of output stage the device has for driving the speaker, so it is quite hard to answer these kinds of questions that are about modifying equipment that has no schematics.

Comment: Site rule: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - this can only be answered by examining the output circuits of the keytar. Then, if it looks OK, you can use a resistor divider attenuator to produce line level signals suitable for connection to a guitar pedal. You might have to guess that bit of course unless you have line level amplitude values for a guitar pedal.

Comment: If the output is pure analog, this isn't too hard.  But if its a class D amplifier I.e. digital PWM output, its not nearly so easy.   PWM output on 'toys' is very common these days... Batteries last alot longer and the drive circuit is much smaller (cheaper).   Without an oscilloscope its impossible for you to know the difference.  But it can be done.  How bad do you want to do this????

Comment: Thanks for feedback both. I've measured and made sure the line levels match, but as a beginner hobbyist I'm basically wondering what else could go wrong and needs to be checked, or what the difference is between a speaker and an input jack. Apologies for the unclear question.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I didn't realise the output could be PWM! I'll check with an oscilloscope as soon as I get the chance!

Comment: If you find it is PWM, post again and I'll share a usable circuit with you. Make sure you tag me using the @ symbol so I know you are trying to get in touch with me.   BTW....Guitars and toys are kind of my two fields of expertise....you landed on something super interesting to me    ;)

Comment: Just try it. You're not going to blow anything up.